# Solve errors in a series of FILTER functions within array brackets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, sorting, google-sheets-filter

I have been working on a budget project on Google Sheets. My goal is for a range of data to be filtered by date (which is represented as an integer between 1 and 31 for the day of the month). All entries in the first two columns are returned if the entry in the third column is equal to 1 (or whatever day of the month for which I am looking). And I require that on ~25 categories, and I want them to all be in one function, so I combined 25 filter functions in an array and they all combined nicely.

My only problem is, what if I don't have any values in one of the categories that correspond to that date. The `FILTER` function returns an error and then the ENTIRE array function fails. I tried using `IFERROR` to return a string, but the array function does not like having strings as an argument.

`={iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$AH$13:$AI$62,Sheet1!$AJ$13:$AJ$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$AK$13:$AL$62,Sheet1!$AM$13:$AM$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$AN$13:$AO$62,Sheet1!$AP$13:$AP$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$AQ$13:$AR$62,Sheet1!$AS$13:$AS$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$AT$13:$AU$62,Sheet1!$AV$13:$AV$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$AW$13:$AX$62,Sheet1!$AY$13:$AY$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$AZ$13:$BA$62,Sheet1!$BB$13:$BB$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$BC$13:$BD$62,Sheet1!$BE$13:$BE$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$BF$13:$BG$62,Sheet1!$BH$13:$BH$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$BI$13:$BJ$62,Sheet1!$BK$13:$BK$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$BL$13:$BM$62,Sheet1!$BN$13:$BN$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$BO$13:$BP$62,Sheet1!$BQ$13:$BQ$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$BR$13:$BS$62,Sheet1!$BT$13:$BT$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$BU$13:$BV$62,Sheet1!$BW$13:$BW$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$BX$13:$BY$62,Sheet1!$BZ$13:$BZ$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$CA$13:$CB$62,Sheet1!$CC$13:$CC$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$CD$13:$CE$62,Sheet1!$CF$13:$CF$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$CG$13:$CH$62,Sheet1!$CI$13:$CI$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$CJ$13:$CK$62,Sheet1!$CL$13:$CL$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$CM$13:$CN$62,Sheet1!$CO$13:$CO$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$CP$13:$CQ$62,Sheet1!$CR$13:$CR$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$CS$13:$CT$62,Sheet1!$CU$13:$CU$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$CV$13:$CW$62,Sheet1!$CX$13:$CX$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$CY$13:$CZ$62,Sheet1!$DA$13:$DA$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$DB$13:$DC$62,Sheet1!$DD$13:$DD$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today");
iferror(sort(FILTER(Sheet1!$DE$13:$DF$62,Sheet1!$DG$13:$DG$62=B5),2,TRUE),"None Today")}`

Each `FILTER`'s first argument refers to two columns that contain the text I want to be returned based on the second argument as a condition (in this case equaling B5 or 1). The sort function organizes this alphabetically. However, if one of these `FILTER` formulas does not filter ANY results that equal B5 (or 1), the entire array function fails. How can I resolve this?

Data lies on Sheet1

The array is placed in B6 on Sheet2
[image: Data Being Filtered]
[image: Filtered Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ...understanding the **`ARRAY_LITERAL ERROR`**:

- until both queries/filters output something then all is good:

  [image: 0]
- however if one of those queries/filters doesn't have anything to output it outputs **`#N/A`** - **`No matches are found in QUERY/FILTER evaluation.`**  - the issue is that **`#N/A`** is only in the 1st cell:

  [image: e]
- but array expects that matrix on both sides to be same (4 columns from both queries/filters):

  [image: 0]
- so we wrap each query into **`IFERROR`** and in case of error we output fake row with 4 fake columns - **`{"","","",""}`** - which will trick the array to output it like:

  [image: 0]
- therefore try like this:

```
={IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$AH$13:$AI$62,Sheet1!$AJ$13:$AJ$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$AK$13:$AL$62,Sheet1!$AM$13:$AM$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$AN$13:$AO$62,Sheet1!$AP$13:$AP$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$AQ$13:$AR$62,Sheet1!$AS$13:$AS$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$AT$13:$AU$62,Sheet1!$AV$13:$AV$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$AW$13:$AX$62,Sheet1!$AY$13:$AY$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$AZ$13:$BA$62,Sheet1!$BB$13:$BB$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$BC$13:$BD$62,Sheet1!$BE$13:$BE$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$BF$13:$BG$62,Sheet1!$BH$13:$BH$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$BI$13:$BJ$62,Sheet1!$BK$13:$BK$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$BL$13:$BM$62,Sheet1!$BN$13:$BN$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$BO$13:$BP$62,Sheet1!$BQ$13:$BQ$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$BR$13:$BS$62,Sheet1!$BT$13:$BT$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$BU$13:$BV$62,Sheet1!$BW$13:$BW$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$BX$13:$BY$62,Sheet1!$BZ$13:$BZ$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$CA$13:$CB$62,Sheet1!$CC$13:$CC$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$CD$13:$CE$62,Sheet1!$CF$13:$CF$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$CG$13:$CH$62,Sheet1!$CI$13:$CI$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$CJ$13:$CK$62,Sheet1!$CL$13:$CL$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$CM$13:$CN$62,Sheet1!$CO$13:$CO$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$CP$13:$CQ$62,Sheet1!$CR$13:$CR$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$CS$13:$CT$62,Sheet1!$CU$13:$CU$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$CV$13:$CW$62,Sheet1!$CX$13:$CX$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$CY$13:$CZ$62,Sheet1!$DA$13:$DA$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$DB$13:$DC$62,Sheet1!$DD$13:$DD$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""});
  IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$DE$13:$DF$62,Sheet1!$DG$13:$DG$62=B5),2,1),{"None Today",""})}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works wonders!